# I want to make a heating element

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, component-selection

I am going to buy a nickel-chromium wire for my heating element.
I want to power it with one li-ion battery (20A 3000mAh)

Intuition tells me that 84W (Draining the battery to its limit) might be sufficient to heat up 5x3x5 (xyz in cm) volume of space to 200°C, but will drain the battery in less than 10 minutes.

I don't know where I can find formulas for precise calculation (regarding heat transfer in accordance to space). But I will deal with this later.

Now my question is, are my calculations correct that I will need a 3.6cm of 0.21Ω wire in order to use the minimum amount of wire needed to carry out 84W (MPT)?

---

Addendum: The LG HG2 is rated to have Internal Resistance: of <20 milliohms.
I doubt that such a low resistance is a big factor.

Comment: What is the voltage? P = V^2/R. 36mm of wire and 84W? 0.21 ohm per cm? Or total? The main problem would be to keep the wire from fusing, that's roughly the length and power of an incandescent lamp filament, which gets white hot and dies very quickly in air.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany When fully charged the battery stands on 4.2V, of course during the discharge period, power will decrease. This is not a problem. I might use a very efficient step-up module or a voltage regulator to keep up stable voltage if I wanted to shorten the life time even further.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes. Well I  think the R of a 24 gauge Nichrome wire is about 1.67Ω per 30cm (roughly) so the minimum length of wire that will have a resistance of 0.21 ohm is 36mm.

Comment: Consider using more wire. You could use 5 pieces 18cm long, in parallel (fold the pieces up to fit the volume without allowing them to touch). That may or may not be enough depending on the actual physical arrangement and what else is in that volume.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks for the tip! :) I will in fact probably use more wire in practice and I also don't need precise heat value, but around 200 +- 25 is perfect. In order to achieve 200o in such a closed area the temperature on the surface of the heating element must be around 450o C.

Comment: how much power it will take to heat the space depends on what is in the space, heating that much air will not take much energy  heating that much water considerably more energy.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to discuss why you are heating the space. What you hope to accomplish. Could you elaborate on that a bit? It may help people guide your efforts. Also, please note that if you drain a LG HG2 at 20A continuously, the battery itself will get quite warm. If it is feasible to blow air over the battery during discharge, that would be a good idea. Adding a DC-DC regulator is probably not a great idea. Since your goal is merely to heat, you really cannot improve efficiency by using a regulator. All the energy will be converted to heat by the resistor.

Comment: I hope the thermal design should be >>90% efficient as this is a lot of stress on a Li-Ion cell.  The power from the battery consumes 10% of the heat since ESR is 10% at best case.

Comment: @Jasen I am trying to heat up air.

Comment: @mkeith Let's say I want to make a mini oven. I knew that the battery will quickly overheat. I don't plan to add things like regulators, as I said I don't need the voltage stable and the battery life reduced. My goal is 1 hour of maximum 500o~ on the surface of a well-distributed heating element. Like a mini oven.

Comment: How much power it takes to heat and maintain heat in your oven will strongly depend on how thermally insulated it is and also on whether you require air to flow through or some similar concern.  If you know what it is you want to heat, you can use the material's mass and specific heat capacity to estimate how much energy is required to change its temperature by a given amount, assuming thermal insulation was perfect.

Comment: @KH It will be pretty much close to perfect. It will be about 99.81% enclosed. I've calculated that if the surface temperature of the wire reaches about 500C it can heat the air inside to the required value. The time it will heat it up for will vary depending on how well are the wires distributed as well as what is the surface area of the wire winding.

Comment: The question is how much wire I need for use with one battery to its full extent.
If I know that, I will know that if I add another battery in series, I will double the power or in parallel, I will double the life time (approximately).

Comment: Be aware that there is a limit to how much current you can safely draw from a lithium ion battery, and that even within that limit(20A for your battery) if you run your heater too hot, the batteries will heat up quite a lot outside the oven, wasting power.  Also note that the Ah ratings of lithium ion batteries are tested at a specific current, and currents above that will give lower Ah ratings, and currents below it will give higher.

Comment: That said, if you want 0.21 ohms from 24 guage nichrome wire, which has 5.4790026 mohm/mm resistance, then you want .21/.005479=38.8mm of wire.  I'd consider using a thinner wire or a material that will allow you more total length.

Comment: Nobody heats up air just because they want the air to be hot. They heat the air up because, maybe, something else is immersed in the air and they want that something else to be hot. Heating the air is the easy part.

Comment: @KH I am not sure my calculations about that are correct, I've never done this before, it is not exactly part of what we call practical experience. There are so many things neither of us ever tried, this is why sites like that are really useful. The 20A drain-out is the maximum not-recommended NSFW value. When I use my product I will regulate the value through a potentiometer. I will use two batteries if I am convinced that it will be needed, but I've seen electric lighters with a heating element that while smaller, heats up very quickly, very powerfully with much smaller battery.

Comment: @mkeith Doesn't matter. Anything after 100C of the air inside will serve its job.

Comment: I think 38mm is too short. It will be VERY hot. You can use two pieces of 76mm wire in parallel. Or 3 pieces of 114mm wire. Or 4 pieces of 152mm in parallel. Etc. You have to keep the wire away from anything that is combustible. Keep an eye on this experiment and be prepared to extinguish a fire. Be prepared to deal with acrid smoke. I am not saying you shouldn't do it. I am just encouraging you to take precautions just in case.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome  (see reference [5]) You need to remember that the resistance changes as a function of temperature.